# Partial auto-correlation function (PACF)

Tags: self-study, autocorrelation, autoregressive, acf-pacf

I wonder how to calculate the partial auto-correlation function of the AR(2) process $Y_t = 0.2 Y_{t−2} + \varepsilon,$  where
$\varepsilon_t ∼ \text{N}(0, \sigma^2)$?
I found ACF as $\rho_h=0.8\rho_{(h-2)}$ where, $\rho_0=1$ and $\rho_1=0$. For computing PACF based on the instruction inpage 69-74 of this [link](https://math.unm.edu/%7Eghuerta/tseries/week4_1.pdf), I think that again PACF of order 0 is equal to 1, but for higher order or equal than 1, PACF it is always zero!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to CV. Please show your attempts as to how you try to approach the problem and where you stumbled.

Comment: In addition to @User1865345' comment, since this is a homework-type question, please consider adding the `self-study` tag; see the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) guide for more details.

Comment: I found ACF as ρ_h=0.8ρ_(h-2) where, ρ_0=1 and ρ_1=0.  
For computing PACF based on the instruction inpage 69-74 of this link (https://math.unm.edu/~ghuerta/tseries/week4_1.pdf), I think that again PACF of order 0 is equal to 1, but for higher order or equal  than 1, PACF  it is always zero!